# select handler returns EndTime date under a wrong field key (id) after updating fields in ScheduleComponent

Tags: reactjs, schedule, syncfusion

I'm updating ScheduleComponent's eventSettings's fields and i'm even creating a new Object instance to make sure the schedule will detect the change (as i did for updating dataSource before)

```
eventSettings.dataSource = eventSettings.dataSource ? [...eventSettings.dataSource] : [];
eventSettings.fields = eventSettings.fields ? { ...eventSettings.fields } : {};
```

Actually i'm changing the EndTime date's field only and the schedule display will be correct after that change.

So to explain it better , initially i pass this set of fields to the schedule:

```
eventSettings.fields: {
    "id": "id",
    "subject": {
        "title": "texxt85",
        "name": "4b0c5bdf-41b0-4478-990c-41d06b9941ae"
    },
    "startTime": {
        "title": "Start Date",
        "name": "0dc9cc20-3c87-4652-a42d-f4cab47e6395"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "title": "Duration",
        "name": "41ef8a19-5ba2-427a-baf7-1685615c5047"
    }
}
```

and then i update the EndTime date's field and pass it again to the schedule via a react setState() call

```
eventSettings.fields: {
    "id": "id",
    "subject": {
        "title": "texxt85",
        "name": "4b0c5bdf-41b0-4478-990c-41d06b9941ae"
    },
    "startTime": {
        "title": "Start Date",
        "name": "0dc9cc20-3c87-4652-a42d-f4cab47e6395"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "title": "End Date",
        "name": "be71318d-b814-4272-b03c-7a9b94442ed2"
    }
}
```

But later when i select a range in the schedule, this is what i get in the select handler:

```
onSelect::args.data: {
    "0dc9cc20-3c87-4652-a42d-f4cab47e6395": "2021-01-10T23:00:00.000Z",
    "41ef8a19-5ba2-427a-baf7-1685615c5047": "2021-01-17T23:00:00.000Z",//<=== wrong date key!!
    "IsAllDay": true,
    "83f4ae53-93a8-4921-a94c-fc96736f9dee": "id-ixg3",
    "1868cae2-f955-4431-8db0-b5afdaf2d2ce": "id-fnlo",
    "93a8de4e-cdcc-4daf-960e-4df7466c128b": "id-h41t",
    "f5f6c085-84cd-4361-aa5d-f1fe6a19e94f": "13b8325c-6365-4920-884b-3d3341c419f3",
    "aaa86022-3c55-4ae0-9dab-fc0f0780f763": "633aa4f1-5a85-11eb-a43b-9d6d9ae8565b",
    "7d3d9187-81a9-4ccf-aea2-9f125b010b97": "633aa4f1-5a85-11eb-a43b-9d6d9ae8565b"
}
```

I'm getting the EndTime's date value under the previous date field name. It seems that the selection on the schedule isn't aware of the eventSettings's fields update that i have done.
Is there a better way to update the eventSettings's fields?
I hope i ll make a plunker for this issue when it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion Support..!

We have validated your reported query and let you know that when you dynamically change the field name that will not be maintained in scheduler previous dataSource. Since you have changed the end time field which is mandatory to render appointments you will not see the appointment.

We have prepared two different samples to show how the schedule behave when you change the mandatory field (end time) and non-mandatory field (subject).

**Changed End time**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-state-change-scheduler-sample-xfrvv6?file=index.js
**Changed Subject**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-state-change-scheduler-sample?file=index.js

> ```
> constructor() {
> super(...arguments);
> this.data = [
>   {
>     Id: 1,
>     Subject: "Testing",
>     StartTime: new Date(2019, 0, 10, 10, 0),
>     EndTime: new Date(2019, 0, 10, 15, 0)
>   }
> ];
> this.state = {
>   data: []
> };   }   componentDidMount() {
> let data = {
>   subject: { name: "Title" }
> };
>
> let that = this;
> setTimeout(() => {
>   that.setState({
>     data
>   });
> }, 2000);   }   render() {
> const { data } = this.state;
> return (
>   <div className="schedule-control-section">
>     <div className="col-lg-9 control-section">
>       <div className="control-wrapper">
>         <ScheduleComponent
>           delayUpdate="true"
>           height="650px"
>           ref={schedule => (this.scheduleObj = schedule)}
>           selectedDate={new Date(2019, 0, 10)}
>           eventSettings={{ fields: data, dataSource: this.data }}
>         >
>           <ViewsDirective>
>             <ViewDirective option="TimelineDay" />
>             <ViewDirective option="TimelineWeek" />
>             <ViewDirective option="TimelineWorkWeek" />
>             <ViewDirective option="TimelineMonth" />
>           </ViewsDirective>
>           <Inject
>             services={[
>              TimelineViews,
>               TimelineMonth,
>               Agenda,
>               Resize,
>               DragAndDrop
>             ]}
>           />
>         </ScheduleComponent>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> );   
> }
> ```

**Note**: If you change the events fields from one state to another then the events present in the older state will maintain with older field names in the Scheduler because the events are mapped based on that field names. Because of that in first sample, appointments are not displayed since end time is mandatory whereas in second sample appointment rendered without subject name after state change.

Kindly try the above scenario and get back to us if you need any further assistance.

Regards,
Hareesh